# dev/sdg is not what I expected

Tags: dual-boot

I have been running a dual boot with XP on the first drive and ubuntu on the second drive. I'm trying  to reinstall ubuntu to my second hd with a live cd but when I use the partioning tool it shows the second drive as /dev/sdg. That is not what I expected. I had asked a question before and from what they had said I was expecting ?dev/sdc,,,does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the first few hard disks would appear in sequence (`/dev/sda` for the first, /dev/sdb` for the second, etc).

A likely source of extra entries are card readers - there appears to be a variety of card reader architectures, some of which emulate an open USB port when no media is inserted, and some which emulate an empty device. In the latter case, you may have a number of `/dev/sdX` devices corresponding to card readers.

You can look in `gparted` (graphical partitioning tool) or use `dmesg | grep sda` in a terminal to look for information about how your system detected each disk. For a hard disk, you should see some lines like:

```
[    2.877980] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
```

(indicating `/dev/sda` is a 2TB hard disk). Repeat for `sdb`, `sdc` etc.

Providing you ensure that you are installing on/partitioning the disk you intend to, what it is called should not matter.

Comment: I installed and what it was called  didn't seem to make any difference. thanks don